# Delay the evaluation of list items

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of random integer within a range:

```
from random import randint

lower  = 0
upper  = 20
length = 10

random_array = [randint(lower, upper) for _ in range(length)]
```

I don't think it is elegant and I come up with another solution:

```
random_array = [randint(lower, upper)] * length
```

But it generate a list of identical integers.

It might be that `randint` is executed before `list`.

I try putting off `randint` with `lambda`:

```
random_array = [(lambda: randint(lower, upper))()] * length
```

but fail.

So I want to know if it's possible to delay the evaluation of items (`randint` in this case) and then have it triggered once the list is assembled?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The OP does not require the numbers to be unique.

Comment: @Selcuk No, they don't.

Comment: The linked duplicate does not match the asker's specific issue. This may be more useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: So you find `[(lambda: randint(lower, upper))()] * length` more elegant than `[randint(lower, upper) for _ in range(length)]` ?

Comment: I think the actual question is _"how do I defer the actual generation of numbers without precomputing the whole list"_? The real answer is the use of a generator function.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks! Very close! But actually I want to know about the order of  item evaluation and list assemble.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the complaint about one of the proposed methods generating a list of identical numbers to mean that it was intended to be a sample of the range. You could sub a list comp with `random.choice` and it would still be better than any of the proposed solutions in the question, and other answers on the linked dupe would also work with easy mods. (e.g. add to list instead of add to set)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

lower = 0
upper = 20
length = 10

random_array = list()
for _ in range(length):
    random_array.append(randint(lower, upper))
print random_array
```

Answer (score -1):

```
random_array = map(lambda _: randint(lower, upper), range(length))
```